# Membership users showing online when they're not?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-membership, user-profile

I have an issue, where by each user in my user list is showing as on-line when I know they're not.

When the page is loaded, they show as offline, but if I refresh the page, they all show as on-line. I'm assuming this is because I'm programmatically accessing their profile information (CommonProfile) to get the data to show on the gridview?

Is there any way to get the profile information without triggering the IsOnline property to be true?

**Update:**
Sorry, code is here. Please be gentle, I'm relatively new to c# & asp.net and I'm still learning.

The code is collecting information from Membership user and the common profiles and adding the fields to a datatable so that i can display the results in a gridview.

```
MembershipUserCollection usersList = Membership.GetAllUsers();
MembershipUserCollection filteredUsers = new MembershipUserCollection();

foreach (MembershipUser user in usersList)
{
    if (!Roles.IsUserInRole(user.UserName, "Admin") && !Roles.IsUserInRole(user.UserName, "Engineering"))
    {
        if (txtFilterCustomerNo.Text.Length > 0)
        {
            ProfileCommon PC = Profile.GetProfile(user.UserName);
            if (PC.CompanyAccountNo == txtFilterCustomerNo.Text.ToUpper())
            {
                filteredUsers.Add(user);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            filteredUsers.Add(user);
        }
    }
}

txtFilterCustomerNo.Text = null;

foreach (MembershipUser user in filteredUsers)
{
    userProfile = Profile.GetProfile(user.UserName);
    string[] userRoles = Roles.GetRolesForUser(user.UserName);

    DataRow orderLine = dataSet.Tables["UserAccounts"].NewRow();
    orderLine["USER_NAME"] = user.UserName;
    orderLine["CREATED"] = user.CreationDate;
    orderLine["LAST_LOGIN"] = user.LastLoginDate;
    orderLine["PASSWORD_CHANGED"] = user.LastLoginDate;
    orderLine["ACTIVE"] = user.IsApproved;
    orderLine["ONLINE"] = user.IsOnline;
    orderLine["LOCKED"] = user.IsLockedOut;
    orderLine["CUSTOMER_NO"] = userProfile.CompanyAccountNo;
    orderLine["HAS_INVENTORY"] = userProfile.HasOwnInventory;
    orderLine["ORDER"] = userRoles.Contains("Order");
    orderLine["REPAIR"] = userRoles.Contains("Repair");
    orderLine["WARRANTY"] = userRoles.Contains("Warranty");
    orderLine["COMMISSIONING"] = userRoles.Contains("Commissioning");
    orderLine["ACCOUNT"] = userRoles.Contains("Account");
    dataSet.Tables["UserAccounts"].Rows.Add(orderLine);
}

if (dataSet.Tables.Contains("UserAccounts"))
{
    GridView1.DataSource = dataSet.Tables["UserAccounts"];
}
```

Comment: The actual code about accessing the user might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you simply looked at the different overloads of GetUser, you would see that some of them take a Boolean called userIsOnline.  If you specify this as false, it will not update the last online timestamp, and will not list them as online.

```
var user = Membership.GetUser(userid, false);
```

EDIT:

I see you are using `GetAllUsers()` rather than `GetUser()`.  There are some problems with `GetAllUsers()` and you cannot rely on the IsOnline property.  Instead, you need to check the `LastActivityDate` field and figure out the difference between that and the current DateTime.  If the amount of time is greater than what you consider "Online" to be, then they are offline, otherwise online.

Comment: I did look for this but in my code that overload doesn't appear to be available. There is probably a better way to achieving what I'm trying to do, but being new to asp.net & c# I'm still learning.

Comment: I assure you, it's there.  Membership's API has not changed since it was introduced 7 years ago.

Comment: I don't doubt that, I've seen the setting, it's just not not available to me in my code (above). Not that I can see? Certainly not in GetAllUsers() anyway...

Comment: ahh... I'll have a look into the LastActivityDate property! Thanks :-D

Comment: When I tried this, it still didn't work (but I know the logic is sound)... so I added the LastActivityDate property to the gridview and discovered that every users's LastActivityDate is the same time and updated everytime I refresh the page... what would be updating the LastActivityDate ??

Comment: OK so I've now learned that GetProfile() has an update LastActivityDate action in the stored procedure (aspnet_Profile_GetProperties stored procedure) ... god know's why!! But I'm not sure how to edit the stored procedure... how do I open it to edit it? I have no idea where it's located! :( Using VS2010